# Smarty calling a function inside a function

Tags: php, function, templates, smarty

we are required to learn **smarty** right now. and i am already into creating my own functions how do i call one function inside another function?

smarty seems to call its function like

```
{function_name param1=val1}
```

i tried to put it inside the **function.myfunction.php** but smarty seems to parse
{ } only inside the .tpl files

is there any way i could call them like

```
function foo($bar){
 $foo = function2(param1,param2);
 return $foo + $bar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty much exactly how you would do it.  Your functions are written in PHP, so you use php, not smarty, notation to call your functions.  You will have to make sure that the function you want to call has been included.

Comment: ok i kind of understand it right now. smarty is just a templating system. it will just display the assigned variables xD